# Flask: number of rows updated

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can i get the number of rows updated/added from a `db.session.commit()` in Flask?

If I try:

```
    for row in csv_data:
        ticket_num = row[0]

        # Generate random UUID token string
        token = uuid.uuid4()

        ticket = Ticket(token, ticket_num, None, None, batch_num)
        db.session.add(ticket)

    num = db.session.commit()
    if num:
        flash(str(num) + ' tickets were uploaded/updated.')
```

I don't get any feedback.

Comment: @PRMoureu I added some details in the example. I can add an entry to my CSV and i dont see a message.

Answer (score 2):

There are properties for the session and you can check what is going to happen in the database. The session has `new`: for objects, which will be added to the database and `dirty`:  for objects, which will be updated:

```
t1 = Ticket(token, ticket_num, None, None, batch_num)
t2 = Ticket(token, ticket_num, None, None, batch_num)
t3 = Ticket.query.filter_by(token='Something to match').first()
t3.token = 'Something new'
db.session.add_all([t1, t2, t3])

# check for new
>>> db.session.new
IdentitySet([<Ticket (transient 140452313747240)>, <Ticket (transient 140452278620112)>])
# check updates
>>> db.session.dirty
>>>db.session.dirty
IdentitySet([<Ticket 2>])  # 2 is ticket id for me
```

You can check the length of course: `len(db.session.new)`

Note this is available before the commit but you will know how many items added and were updated.

Comment: so based on  @Joost's comment below, wouldn't i be creating a duplicate on t3 if i explicitly add it? ie, in my loop, `db.session.add(t3)` < creates duplicate row

Comment: The Example is demonstrating how you can do it not the logic. And in this example if `t3` is exists on the database it will not duplicate i only change the yoke field and save it back.

Answer (score 0):

`db.session.commit()` does not return anything, so you might want to try and keep track of the number of things you're adding to the db, for instance by:

```
flash(str(len(csv_data)) + ' tickets were uploaded/updated.')
```

Comment: Right, but some of that data could be duplicate of what's already in the DB. There's no way to capture the updated/added count?

Comment: So you just want to see then entries which are different? What is the primery key of the table?

Comment: there's a unique `id` col for the ticket table which is the pk

Comment: So by reading in the csv, you create a bunch of new tickets. You're not checking if these tickets are in the database already whatsoever, so how should sql-alchemy know?